# Current in a triangle wire

Tags: electric-circuits

[image]

Suppose I have 3 ideal wire with zero resistance forming a triangle. Suppose the current input is 1A and 2A. It is obvious the output is 3A, but what is the current in the 3 wire(I1,I2)?

I tried using KVl but it failed as R is zero and this caused the problem unsolvable.

My teacher said that the problem was unsolvable and impractical because in real life there was always resistance.

But aren't there superconductors?
What will occur if we use those.

Comment: my intuition is that it will be the same situation as 3 wire has same resistance, but I'm not sure

Comment: It will be *undetermined*, I think.

Comment: it is strange though because this set up is possible to make in real life using superconductors and the ans is we can't predict it.

Answer (score 3):

> My teacher said that the problem was unsolvable

Your teacher is correct. There are an infinite number of possible solutions. $I_2$ can be anything and then $I_1=3-I_2$.

With superconductors there still is insufficient information. You would need to know the loop current, e.g. by measuring the magnetic field.